# voting popularity contest

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, rules, voting

I recently noticed that on many popularity contests the earlier answers get more upvotes than the ones that were submitted later. This effect is - I think - amplified by arranging the answers so that the most upvoted answers are displayed on top. On the one hand later submissions can use idea of earlier ones of course, but on the other hand I think many nice answers get 'lost' because they were submitted later.

- What is your opinion on that?

I thought perhaps one could divide the popularity contests into two phases: First submitting answers until a certain deadline, and then an anonymous voting untill another deadline where the votes are made public. Another idea would be instead of sorting the answers by upvotes just randomly shuffle all aswers each 15min or each time where the site is loaded.

These are just some thought, and perhaps you do not even see it this way and thats why I'd like to hear your opinions on that.

Comment: Answers are sorted according to the votes they received only if the user decided to. Otherwise they can be sorted by last activity or age. Only the accepted answer is always first.

Comment: It's not about being pop-con or not: the same holds for any question which gets more than a dozen answers.

Comment: @plannapus, that's not quite true. If the user hasn't decided to sort by something else, sorting by votes is the default. This makes sense on Q&A sites.

Comment: It's simple. Award a bounty to the answers you think are great. That's what I did on the *Images with All Colors* and the *Mona Lisa in the Palette of American Gothic*.

Comment: @plannapus changing the default sort from votes to active might make sense here